# I can't get CSS working

Tags: r, shiny

So I'm new to CSS and I'm trying figure out how to incorporate it into R. I had this part working yesterday and I don't know what I've done to mess it up since then. The program itself works fine I just can't get the CSS working, except for the lines `.tableinput-container` and `.data`.

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("Stats",
 tabPanel("Data",
       tags$head(
         tags$style(type = "text/css"
                    , ".navbar-inner{background-color: rgb(202,202,202); background-image: none; font-family: Arial; font-size: small; }"
                    , ".navbar .brand {background-color: default color: default; font-family: Arial; color: black;}"    
                    , "table.data {width: 300px; border-color: black;}"
                    , ".well {width: 80%; background-color: NULL; border: 0px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgb(255, 255, 255) inset;}"
                    , ".tableinput .hide {display: table-header-group; background-color: rgb(204,204,204);  align-items: center; text-align: center; align-self: center;}"
                    , ".tableinput-container {width: 100%; text-align: center;}"
                    , ".tableinput-buttons {margin: 10px;}"
                    , ".data {background-color: rgb(255,255,255);}"
                    , ".table th, .table td {text-align: center; border-color:black;}"

         )),
matrixInput('data', 'Add Rows', data.frame("A"="","B"="","C"="","D"=""))
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done a new tags$style() call for each line in the past... Maybe try that. Here's an example from one of my shiny apps:

```
sidebarPanel(
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="css/styles.css"),
      tags$script(type = 'text/javascript', src = 'js/responsiveTable.js'),      
      tags$style(type="text/css", "label.radio { display: inline-block; }", ".radio input[type=\"radio\"] { float: none; }"),
      tags$style(type="text/css", "select { max-width: 200px; }"),
      tags$style(type="text/css", "textarea { max-width: 185px; }"),
      tags$style(type="text/css", ".jslider { max-width: 200px; }"),
      tags$style(type='text/css', ".well { padding: 12px; margin-bottom: 5px; max-width: 280px; }"),
      tags$style(type='text/css', ".span4 { max-width: 280px; }")
    ),
```